# How can I exactly position an image\table in a document?

Tags: tables, graphics, environments

I am trying to insert an image in my LaTex document using either straight ahead the `\includegraphics` argument or the figure environment. One problem however that I am facing is that I cannot position exactly my image in the document. From what I see using `\begin{center}` for example sets the image in the center, however I am looking for more precision. Is there any way to exactly determine the position of my image (Determine for example the distance from say the left border of the page)? The same question applies for tables as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: an image (or table) is positioned exactly like a letter: `\noindent\hspace{3.1cm}\includegraphics{..}`  will be 31mm from the left margin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much! Your advice solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

an image (or table) is positioned exactly like a letter:

```
  \noindent\hspace{3.1cm}\includegraphics{..}
```

will be 31mm from the left margin